# Jquery setTimeout loop while

Tags: jquery, while-loop, settimeout

My very simple loop while doesn't work, it seems that the problem comes from setTimeout.
I try to code a little game with a countdown.

```
while ( there is time ) {
  // actions possible to do

  //my timer function
}
```

So if c is the time

```
var c = 30;

while (c > 0)
{ 
c -= 1;      
setTimeout( $("#timer").html(c) , 1000);   
};
```

It is not just a countdown, but the users have to be able to make actions during the countdown.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: `c` is overwritten at each iteration, and `$("#timer").html(c)` is called immediately. Where's the function wrapper?

Comment: Purpose of writing such code hasn't been mentioned. Question itself is very much unclear.

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout` expects a function as its first parameter. This function will be called when the time is out. But what you provided in your example code is the result of calling `$("#timer").html(c)`

The correct way of using `setTimeout` should be:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  // blah blah
}, 1000);
```

I guess you are tring to do something like a countdown, and here's a example code:

```
function countdown(count, container) {      // declare the countdown function.
   var $container = $(container);
   (function step() {
    $container.html(count);               // set the timer html
    if (count-- > 0) {                      // decrement counter and stop when counter reaches 0
      setTimeout(step, 1000);               // if counter is not 0, then issue the next timeout
    }
  })();                                     // call step immediately
}
countdown(10, '#timer');
```

live demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/cazSn/2/

PS: use `setInterval` will be easier if you are really trying to implement a countdown.

Comment: Prefix `c = 10;` by `var`, *or* move it to the function parameter: `(function countdown(c) { ... })(10);`.

Comment: Now you've changed the code, I recommend to cache the jQuery selector as well.

Comment: What about cancelling this countdown function?

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` will be better.

```
var c = 100; 
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    if (c>0){
        $("#timer").html(c);
        c--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand what are you doing with that loop and `c` variable, but you misuse the `setTimeout` function

```
setTimeout( 1000, function(){$("#timer").html(c)};
```

Or the not recommended way:

```
setTimeout('$("#timer").html(c)', '1000';
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)